# My environmentObject isn't working.I tap on navigationLink and see nothing in there

Tags: swiftui

My environmentObject isn't working.I tap on navigationLink and see nothing in there.
I change  note but it does not get updated.I made viewModel and share data from it everywhere I need it
I made the second TextEditor to do changes to my notes, but I cannot see changes.I just want to write smith and data should be updated
So how can I fix that?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WhatToDoAppApp: App {
    @StateObject private var vm = NoteViewModel()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(vm)
        }
    }
}
```

```
//ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: NoteViewModel
    
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(vm.notes) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: NoteDetailView()) {
                    Text(item.task)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                  }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: vm.deleteTask)
                .onMove(perform: vm.moveTask)
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText) {
                if !searchResult.isEmpty {
                ForEach(searchResult) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: NoteDetailView()) {
                    Text(item.task)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Notes")
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                    Color.clear
                    .frame(maxHeight: 40)
                    .background(.gray.opacity(0.7))
              
                HStack {
                    Spacer(minLength: 160)
                    Text("\(vm.notes.count) notes")
                        .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.3))
                    
                    Spacer()
                     Button {
                         showSheet = true
                       } label: {
                           Image(systemName: "square")
                               .font(.largeTitle)
                               .padding(.trailing)
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                NoteView()
            }
        }
    }
    var searchResult: [ToDoItem] {
        guard !searchText.isEmpty else { return vm.notes }
        return vm.notes.filter { $0.task.contains(searchText) }
       }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
                .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.light)
        }
        .environmentObject(NoteViewModel())
    }
}
```

```
//NoteDetailView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct NoteDetailView: View {
       @EnvironmentObject var vm: NoteViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $vm.text)
                
        Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct NotedetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NoteDetailView().environmentObject(NoteViewModel())
    }
}
```

```
//NoteView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct NoteView: View {
//    @State private var text = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: NoteViewModel
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextEditor(text: $vm.text)
            }
            .padding()
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        addTask()
                        dismiss()
                        vm.text = ""
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Done")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func addTask() {
        vm.add(ToDoItem(task: vm.text))
    }
}

struct NoteView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NoteView()
            .environmentObject(NoteViewModel())
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct ToDoItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var task : String
}

class NoteViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published  var notes = [ToDoItem]()
    
    @Published var text = ""
    let saveKey = "SavedKey"
    
    init() {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: saveKey) {
            if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ToDoItem].self, from: data) {
                notes = decoded
                return
            }
        }
        notes = []
    }
    
   private func save() {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(notes) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: saveKey)
        }
    }
    
    func add(_ note: ToDoItem) {
        notes.append(note)
        save()
    }
    
     func deleteTask(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        indexSet.forEach { index in
            self.notes.remove(at: index)
            save()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you call `NoteDetailView()` you are creating a different instance, one does not know about the other. use the `@EnvironmentObject` value directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detail view should be a `@Binding`, and you can use the array that you have in the viewModel as an Bindable `List` here the fixes:

```
 List {
            ForEach($vm.notes) { $item in
                NavigationLink(item.task, destination: NoteDetailView(note: $item))
            }
```

The detail view should look like this:

```
struct NoteDetailView: View {
@Binding var note: ToDoItem

@EnvironmentObject var vm: NoteViewModel
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextEditor(text: $note.task)
            
        Spacer()
    }
    .onDisappear {
        vm.save()
    }
}}
```

This way every time the user updates and closes the modal, the list will be saved.

[image]

Comment: But I have an error Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'StringProtocol'

Comment: You have to update the searchable too